# How to deploy dotnet app from self-hosted runner using Github Actions?

Tags: .net-core, deployment, server, github-actions

I've been playing around with Github Actions and I'm trying to work out a way to deploy a Dotnet Core API to my Linux server. I've configured the Self Hosted runner and am able to build my application successfully.

The issue arises when I go to run the application it doesn't seem to pick up my `appsetting.json` configurations. It seems like it is running the app but it will run on the default ports of 5000, 5001(https) instead of my configured ports. It also cannot find my DB connection strings from the appsettings. What is the correct way to trigger it to run on my server from Github Actions?

Running the app manually on the server using `dotnet myapp.dll` is working correctly without issue. My actions workflow yml is below.

```
name: dotnet package

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  build:

  runs-on: self-hosted

  steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Setup .NET Core SDK 6.0.x
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1.7.2
      with:
        dotnet-version: '6.0.x'
    - name: Install dependencies
      un: dotnet restore
    - name: Build
      run: dotnet build --configuration Release --no-restore
    - name: Deploy
      run: dotnet ./myapp/bin/Release/net6.0/myapp.dll
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up deploying the app as a service on the linux server and publishing the files to the server which now will auto update the app with the new files. Pretty much followed this article word for word to get the results I was after. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Answer (score 0):

Did you not include `appsetting.json` when you released it?

Comment: The file exists within the folder if that's what you mean? Is there a specific way I need to include it?